# What is $Df$ in Multivariable Calculus?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I wasn't in class for a week of lecture because of medical problems.
It seems to do with differentiation but I cannot find how to find $Df$ given $f$ (don't even know what Df stands for)

Here is the problem:

$$\text{let } f(x,y)=
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} \\ 
\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x} \\
\end{array}
\right\} 
$$

find $Df(-1,2)$

and this extra part:
verify if f is differentiable on its domain. Justify.

Any explanations and links to articles are greatly appreciated

Comment: hmm after further analysis of the answer it seems to be
to go through each function-piece and differentiate with respect to each variable (partial derivatives) that f is a function for (x and y in this case)
now if someone can explain the extra part

Comment: D is  the differential of $f$. you'll find all you need in any book or with a simple web search.